# Wordpress - Iframe can't find .html in path

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, resize

```
<div id="content-inner">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/iframe_resize.js"></script>
        <iframe id="iframe_intg_container" frameborder="0" src="http://rezervacija.adcparking.com/integration/?type=full&c=a9d15799d4c7b5c" scrolling="no" style="width: 960px; height: 500px;"></iframe>
    </div>
```

This code is in custom page, path is http://www.address.com/informacija/adcparking/

Iframe try to access height in file "iframe_resize.**html** so i get error in browser console

> GET
>   http://www.address.com/informacija/adcparking/iframe_resize.html?height=665
>   404 (Not Found)
>   /informacija/adcparking/iframe_resize.html?height=665:1

So question is there to put that iframe_resize.**html** ?

Comment: You are linking to a script `/iframe_resize.js`. Can you post the source or a link to it? My guess is that this is what is requesting the iframe_resize.html and there is a path issue somewhere.

Comment: iframe_resize.js  

  `function resizeIframeHeight( h ) {
document.getElementById( 'iframe_intg_container' ).style.height = h + 'px';
};`
  
Both files i have  
  
iframe_resize.html
  

`<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

function getFirstParamFromLocation() {

var pair = window.location.search.substring( 1 );

var parts = pair.split( '=' );

return parts;

}

var nData = getFirstParamFromLocation();

try {

nHeight = parseInt( nData[1] );

window.top.resizeIframeHeight( nHeight );

} catch( e ) {

};

//]]>

</script>`

Comment: So you do have a file named iframe_resize.html? But it's not in the same directory? Then you have two options, either put it in the right directory or update the path to it in the other file. Not sure what the problem is.